# Spring : How to create similar beans in Spring Boot dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

*I want to create multiple similar beans dynamically based on the properties file to replace the duplicate code.*

**Is that a good idea ?**

**My original duplicate code:**

```
@Configuration
@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class HessianFactory {


    public static PubHessianServiceExporter createHessianService(Object service, Class clazz) {
        PubHessianServiceExporter exporter = new PubHessianServiceExporter();
        exporter.setService(service);
        exporter.setServiceInterface(clazz);
        return exporter;
    }

    @Bean("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/1")
    public PubHessianServiceExporter curriculumScheduleService1() {
        return HessianFactory.createHessianService(StudentAppServiceFactory.curriculumScheduleServices.get(1), CurriculumScheduleService.class);
    }

    @Bean("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/2")
    public PubHessianServiceExporter curriculumScheduleService2() {
        return HessianFactory.createHessianService(StudentAppServiceFactory.curriculumScheduleServices.get(2), CurriculumScheduleService.class);
    }

    @Bean("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/3")
    public PubHessianServiceExporter curriculumScheduleService3() {
        return HessianFactory.createHessianService(StudentAppServiceFactory.curriculumScheduleServices.get(3), CurriculumScheduleService.class);
    }

    @Bean("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/5")
    public PubHessianServiceExporter curriculumScheduleService5() {
        return HessianFactory.createHessianService(StudentAppServiceFactory.curriculumScheduleServices.get(5), CurriculumScheduleService.class);
    }
}
```

I have tried with the code given below :

```
@Configuration
@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class HessianFactory {

    @Value("${sign-sys-ids}")
    private String[] signSysIds;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;


    public static HessianServiceExporter createHessianService(Object service, Class clazz) {
        HessianServiceExporter exporter = new HessianServiceExporter();
        exporter.setService(service);
        exporter.setServiceInterface(clazz);
        return exporter;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws BeansException {
        Arrays.stream(signSysIds).forEach(
            i -> {
                HessianServiceExporter hessianServiceExporter = createHessianService(
                    StudentAppServiceFactory.curriculumScheduleServices.get(Integer.parseInt(i)), CurriculumScheduleService.class);
                beanFactory.registerSingleton("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/" + i, hessianServiceExporter);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

But the above code is not working.

**curriculumScheduleServices** is map of curriculumScheduleService with different `index(i)`

Comment: what is not working? the above code is perfectly fine. Where do you execute `beanFactory.registerSingleton`? In `@PostConstruct` method?

Comment: yes, it is in `@PostConstruct`, not working mean that i cant get the bean in spirngcontext

Comment: it will error:```org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Hessian skeleton invocation failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Hessian exporter has not been initialized```

Comment: where is this exception thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws BeansException {
    Arrays.stream(signSysIds).forEach(
        i -> {
            String beanName = "/svc/curriculumScheduleService/" + i;
            AbstractBeanDefinition bean = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(PubHessianServiceExporter.class)
                .addPropertyValue("service", StudentAppServiceFactory.curriculumScheduleServices.get(Integer.parseInt(i)))
                .addPropertyValue("serviceInterface", CurriculumScheduleService.class)
                .getBeanDefinition();
            beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, bean);
        }
    );
}
```

it work.

Comment: The interface ConfigurableBeanFactory does not have registerBeanDefinition method. For doing it you should autowire BeanDefinitionRegistry. In most cases inner class implements ConfigurableBeanFactory and BeanDefinitionRegistry. So you just need to check instanceof.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing `@DependsOn` somewhere in your code. Since you are creating beans programmatically there's no guarantee when those beans are going to be available in application context. To enforce order, you can add `@DependsOn` to a configuration that uses it. See Example below

Configuration that depends on other configuration that creates beans programatically

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("TestConfiguration2")
public class TestConfiguration1 {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/1")
  private DummyClass dummyClass1;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/2")
  private DummyClass dummyClass2;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/3")
  private DummyClass dummyClass3;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/5")
  private DummyClass dummyClass5;

  @PostConstruct
  public void printBeans() {
    System.out.println(dummyClass1.getVal());
    System.out.println(dummyClass2.getVal());
    System.out.println(dummyClass3.getVal());
    System.out.println(dummyClass5.getVal());
  }
}
```

Configuration that creates beans programatically

```
@Configuration("TestConfiguration2")
public class TestConfiguration2 {

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  @PostConstruct
  public void setup() {
    String[] array = {"1", "2", "3", "5"};
    Arrays.stream(array).map(Integer::parseInt).forEach(i -> {
      System.out.println("creating new bean");
      beanFactory.registerSingleton("/svc/curriculumScheduleService/" + i, new DummyClass(i));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it will error: ```java org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Hessian skeleton invocation failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Hessian exporter has not been initialized```

Comment: can you put all of your configuration in your question? The answer explains how you generally solve this type of problem. It looks like you have something specific to your use case.

Comment: has put all code. i search from google and try to use BeanDefinition but i not work

Comment: can you also add a code where benas /svc/curriculumScheduleService/1... are used
where they are injected?